# How to dockrize angular js project with separeted google tag for DEV and PROD?

Tags: angularjs, nginx, gitlab, dockerfile, kubernetes-ingress

I have an Angular JS project. I am first building the docker image and deploying it into Kubernetes. I want to use a separate Google Tag Manager for DEV and PROD. How can I achieve it?

I have tried with dev.index.html and prod.index.html. But in docker file, I am able to use DEV Build or Production. Unable to segregate Dev deployment with Dev build and Prod deployment with Prod build.